# how to execute sql select query with minimum runtime

Tags: php, mysql, sql, normalization, database-normalization

I want to select from a table and then make select for each of them.

**tables:**

```
category
+====+=======+
| id | title |
+====+=======+
this table has list of category

email
+====+=======+==========+=============+
| id | eMail | domainId | elseColumns |
+====+=======+==========+=============+
this table has list of emails but domains are in another table

domain
+====+========+=============+
| id | domain | elseColumns |
+====+========+=============+
list of domains which used in email

subscriber_category
+========+============+
| userId | categoryId |
+========+============+
list of emails in categories
```

now the question is  how can i list categories and count of emails in them with minimum runtime? my try is waiting 20sec for 200000 email and 20 category.

**sql:**

```
SELECT category.*,
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT subscriber_category.userId) FROM subscriber_category
    JOIN email ON email.id=subscriber_category.userId
    JOIN domain ON domain.id=email.domainId
WHERE subscriber_category.categoryId=category.id
    AND email.blackList=0
    AND domain.blackList=0
) AS qty
FROM category WHERE category.userId=1 ORDER BY category.title ASC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT c.*,
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sc.userId)
        FROM subscriber_category sc JOIN
             email e
             ON e.id = sc.userId JOIN
             domain d
             ON d.id = e.domainId
       WHERE sc.categoryId = c.id AND e.blackList = 0 AND d.blackList = 0
      ) AS qty
FROM category c
WHERE c.userId = 1
ORDER BY c.title ASC;
```

The structure is quite reasonable and indexes should help performance.  The first index is on `category(userId, title, id)`.  This index *should* be used for the `WHERE` clause, the `ORDER BY`, and the correlated subquery.

Next, I assume that you have indexes on the `id` columns in `email` and `domain`.  You could make these slightly more applicable to the query if you include the `blacklist` flag as a second column in the index.  More importantly, you want an index on `subscriber_category(categoryId, userId)`.  I would also recommend removing the `count(distinct)` if it is not necessary.

Comment: my God!!!! your record is `1.0499sec`. I changed indexes as you said. is it makes deference if I set relations between tables?

Comment: @Pooya . . . I don't understand the question in your comment.

Comment: I want to know is it help if I set Foreign keys of tables? i.e: `email.domainId to domain.id`

Comment: @Pooya . . . Foreign keys do not directly affect performance, except in one indirect way:  they require that the column(s) in the reference table be a primary key or unique, so there is an index on them.  That would not help in this case.